# Customizing the MonthCalendar control

Tags: c#, monthcalendar

I am trying to modify the MonthCalendar control to only show tuesdays or only Tuesdays are clickable.  I tried looking for an owner draw or overriding the Paint or DayRender Method.  None of those options were available in VS 2008?

Any other ideas?

Thank you